# Inserting html elements while DOM is changing

Tags: javascript

My code should insert HTML content in all divs that have a predefined class name, without using jQuery and at least compatible with IE8 (so no getElementsbyClass).

The html:

```
<div class="target">1</div>
<div class="target">2</div>
<div class="target">3</div>
<div class="target">4</div>
```

The javascript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (wwi in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[wwi].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + "target" + ' ') > -1) {
            elems[wwi].innerHTML = "YES";
            //elems[wwi].innerHTML = "<div>YES!</div>";
        }
    }
```

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rDdEZ/).

As you can see inside each div the word YES is printed. Well the if you comment `elems[wwi].innerHTML = "YES";` and replace that for  `elems[wwi].innerHTML = "<div>YES!</div>"` the code fails. I suppose is because inserting div elements modify the DOM and in consequence the FOR cycle fails. Am i right?

Well i can solve this pretty ugly by recalling the for cycle each time i make an innerHTML, and when i insert the code i can add a class (like data-codeAlreadyInserted=1) to ignore the next time the FOR pass in that div. But again, this is pretty much a very bad solution since for an average site with many tags I can even freeze the user browser.

What do you think? lets suppose i dont know the amount of tags i insert on each innerHTML call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I suppose is because inserting div elements modify the DOM and in consequence the FOR cycle fails. Am i right?"*

Pretty much. Your `elems` list is a live list that is updated when the DOM changes. Because you're adding a new div on every iteration, the list keeps growing and so you never get to the end.

To avoid this, you can either do a reverse iteration,

```
for (var i = elems.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    // your code
}
```

or convert the list to an Array.

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(elems[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: @DomingoSL: Your `elems` list. And actually, whether or not it becomes an infinite loop or simply skips some elements will depend on the browser's implementation of `for-in`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a copy of the live node list:

```
var nodes = [];
for (var i = 0, n = elems.length; i < n; ++i) {
    nodes.push(elems[i]);
}
```

and then use a proper `for` loop, not `for ... in` to iterate over the array:

```
for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

`for ... in` should *only* be used on objects, not arrays.

Comment: can you please give an example?

Comment: @DomingoSL I thought I had...?!

Comment: Your `.slice.call` isn't going to work in IE8, because IE8 requires native objects as the `this` value of its native methods.

Comment: I mean using my code, im not a front end dev, so im having issues to understand your answer, if you provide me a complete code maybe i can get it faster

Comment: @CrazyTrain damned IE...  Which of those objects isn't a native object, though?  Would it work as `Array.prototype.slice.call(elems, 0)` ?

Comment: @Alnitak: The `elems` is a host object, so unfortunately IE8 won't allow it to be substituted as the `this` value of `.slice()`. And no, the `Array.prototype.slice` is just a different path to the same method, so you'll experience the same failure. `[].slice === Array.prototype.slice; // true`

Comment: @CrazyTrain I am _so_ glad I don't have to regularly write code for that non-conformant piece of shite that is any IE < 10

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use replaceChild instead of innerHTML. It works better and it's way faster:

```
var newEl = elem[wwi].cloneNode(false);
newEl.innerHTML = html;
elem[wwi].parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, elem[wwi]);
```

Comment: So cloning a node, settings its `.innerHTML` and then swapping the original with the clone is faster than just setting the `.innerHTML` of the original?

Comment: @Crazy-Train, yes, is faster on all browsers except for IE... I've tested it myself, I have a single page app that became much more responsive when I changed innerHTML to replaceChild....

Comment: But you're still using `.innerHTML` in your answer. Did your tests do the same?

Comment: Yes, I'm still using innerHTML but on an empty node! Which is very different than using it on a node full of children... it really improved (a lot!!) my app's performance.

Comment: cloneNode(false) means it will clone only the element, not it's children.